# Accessing state from callback

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having trouble accessing the component state from a callback.

The value of the state `num` changes correctly, but such changes are not visible to the callback function defined at load time.

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

class MyObject {
  callback: (() => void);

  constructor(callback: () => void) {
    this.callback = callback;
  }
};

export const TestPage = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState<number>(0);

  // will print the changing values
  console.log(`num: ${num}`);

  const counter = useState<MyObject>(() => new MyObject(() => {
    // will always print 0
    console.log(`from callback. num: ${num}`);
  }))[0];

  const btnClick = () => {
    setNum((new Date()).getTime());
    counter.callback();
  };

  return (
      <div>Test, num: {num}
        <div>
          <button onClick={btnClick}>click to update state</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

the above doesn't happen with the plain non-React code as follows

```js
  let myVar = 0;
  const obj = new MyObject(() => console.log(`myVar: ${myVar}`));
  obj.callback(); // prints 0
  myVar = 1;
  obj.callback(); // prints 1
```

**edit**: I've tried to reproduce the problem with closures, but I cannot

```
 const makeFun = (callback: (() => void)) => {
    return () => {
      callback();
    }
  }
  let myVar = 0;
  const f1 = makeFun(() => console.log(`myVar: ${myVar}`));
  myVar = 1;
  const f2 = makeFun(() => console.log(`myVar: ${myVar}`));
  f1(); // prints 1
  f2(); // prints 1
```

so I suspect is something specific to React and useState.

Any ideas?

**edit#2**: solution. this is how to make it visible in non-React code.

```
let callbackPersistent: (() => void);
const createCallback = (callback: (() => void)) => {
  if (!callbackPersistent) {
    callbackPersistent = callback;
  }
  return callbackPersistent;
}

const myFunction = (num:number) => {
  const callback = createCallback(() => console.log(`callback num: ${num}`));
  callback();
};
```

and then call it as

```
  myFunction(0); // prints 0
  myFunction(1); // prints 0
```

there's only one instance of the callback and it points to the value it saw once first created.

**edit#3**:

A reasonable solution can be found using `useRef` and `useEffect`, as follows:

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";

class MyObject {
  callback: (() => void);

  constructor(callback: () => void) {
    this.callback = callback;
  }
};

export const TestPage = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState<number>(0);
  const numRef = useRef(num);

  // will print the changing values
  console.log(`num: ${num}`);

  const counter = useState<MyObject>(() => new MyObject(() => {
    // will always print the latest value
    console.log(`from callback. num: ${numRef.current}`);
  }))[0];

  useEffect(()=> {numRef.current = num}, [num]);

  const btnClick = () => {
    setNum(new Date().getTime());
    counter.callback();
  };

  return (
      <div>Test, num: {num}
        <div>
          <button onClick={btnClick}>click to update state</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

`useRef` guarantees that `numRef` is always the same object over multiple invocations. When the value of `num` changes the `onEffect` call will update the `numRef.current` value, which is then accesses by the the callback. Only one instance of the callback and of `numRef` exist, making sure the changes are correctly picked up