# React hook state and passing it to other classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question about react hook's useState. Shouldn't the state which I have passed to the ModelClass through the constructor be always the latest one, but instead it memorizes the first state which is passed into the class's constructor. I would like to have the latest reference of the state in my class.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";

class ModelClass{

  constructor(state, setState){
    this.state = state;
    this.setState = setState
  }

  stateHasChanged(){
    console.log(this.state);
  }
}

export default function App(){

  const [state, setState] = useState("default");
  const [model, _] = useState(()=> new ModelClass(state, setState));

  useEffect(()=>{
    setState("first change");
    setTimeout(()=>setState("second change"), 2000);
  },[]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    model.stateHasChanged();
  },[state]);

  return (<div>
    This
   </div>);

}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish, because I could almost be certain, this is not the way to do it...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010671/accessing-state-from-callback/

Comment: But shouldn't state refer to the latest state?

Comment: No it should not. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The function you pass to `useState` is only invoked the first time the component is rendered.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I thought it was a fixed reference to a getter.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question, check [Accessing state from callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010671/accessing-state-from-callback/).

IMHO you should use `useRef` if you want to access the latest state.

you basically have just one instance of `model`, and it points to the first `state` passed.